# highcharts scale chart to width

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, highcharts

I'm trying to set an explicit width on my chart, 400px, but when I do this the chart gets cut off! I just want it to scale down to that size, as it's going in an Iphone mobile site,

does anyone know what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

I've had to deal with this issue when importing blog contents into jquery mobile.  You can't always count on people who write the entries to make the images iPhone sized (nor should they).  So, here is how I solved the issue.

In English:  When a "page" is initialized, look through every image on the page that has a width and if it's larger than the width of the device, erase the height and set the width to 100%.

This has the added benefit of making the image larger if you rotate your device.

Here is the code...

```
$("div").live("pageinit", function(){
    var $images = $("img[width]");
    $images.each(function(){ 
        try{
            var $image = $(this);
            var currentWidth = Number($image.attr("width"));
            if(currentWidth > 320){
                $image.width("100%");
                $image.removeAttr("height");
            }
        }catch(e){
            /*alert("page init error\n image scale fail\n"+e)*/
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Shane, thanks again for the response. That's a nice little solution to pulling in content like that. Highcharts renders out a canvas so I don't think this is the problem for me. It sets the size of my canvas fine but the graph inside doesn't adjust to its container size :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To fix it you can scale the container with this css:

`.chart-container { transform: scale(0.75); }`

And increase the highcharts font-size

`// For a pie chart:
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
    style: { fontSize: '22px' }
  }
}`